# How do I represent a set of possible equalities in column form

Tags: equations

I am trying to write the following expression in LaTeX. There should be a set of possible values written in column forms with the conditions written adjacent to them in the column.
[image]

Answer (score 9):

The `cases` environment from `amsmath` is made precisely for that purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtx}
\begin{document}
\[
\int_{x_0}^{x_0+L} \sin\Bigl( \frac{2\pi rx}{L} \Bigr) 
   \sin\Bigl( \frac{2\pi px}{L} \Bigr)\, dx = 
   \begin{cases}
       0               & \text{for } r = p = 0, \\
       \frac{1}{2} L   & \text{for } r = p > 0, \\
       0               & \text{for } r \neq p,
   \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here, the package `newtx` is just used for the font, it is not necessary for the formatting of the equation.

Comment: Incidentally: which is preferred here, `\text{for } r=p=0,` or `\text{for $r=p=0$,}` ? Semantically the second looks more grounded to me, but I don't know if there are any differences in formatting.